# when am setting styles to to tab page indicator it is not applying in android

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

When am trying to set style to TitlePageIndicator in android it is not getting applied.
The following lines are my styles.xml code when am trying to set to my fragment activity these style is not applying.

```
      <style name="StyledIndicators" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
            <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
            <item name="vpiLinePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomLinePageIndicator</item>
            <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTitlePageIndicator</item>
            <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
            <item name="vpiUnderlinePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomUnderlinePageIndicator</item>
        </style>

        <style name="CustomTitlePageIndicator">
            <item name="android:background">#18FF0000</item>
            <item name="footerColor">#FFAA2222</item>
            <item name="footerLineHeight">1dp</item>
            <item name="footerIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
            <item name="footerIndicatorStyle">underline</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#AA000000</item>
            <item name="selectedColor">#FF000000</item>
            <item name="selectedBold">true</item>
        </style>


        <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator</item>
            <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#FF555555</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
            <item name="android:divider">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_divider</item>
          <!--   <item name="android:dividerPadding">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item> -->
            <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
            <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
            <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
        </style>

        <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
            <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        </style>
```

In the manifest file am setting theme as like this

```
      <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators">

            </activity>
```

but any styles are not applying to my titles. When i am executing view pager indicator downloaded sample application it's working fine.

Comment: Please anyone reply to my question.